# For Express.js 4.x, is it possible to use express.static twice?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, static

I would like to show a custom 404 page (containing html, css, img, and ico). I know my 404 folder works when I replace the first public static homepage. However, I believe I am either not using routes the right way or it is not possible to set up two static folders.

I do not want to use template view engines at all. I want everything to be rendered on the frontend.

My project looks as follows:

```
404
--index.html
--error.css
--404.jpg
bin
--server.js
public
--index.html
routes
--index.js
package.json
app.js
```

app.js

```
...
var index = require(./routes/index); //works
...
app.use(favicon(__dirname + '/public/content/images/logo.ico'));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(jsonParser);
app.use(urlencodedParser);
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public'))); //love it
app.use('/', index); //this is fine
...
```

index.js

```
var express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
var router = express.Router();

router.use(function timeLog(req, res, next) {
    console.log('Time: ', Date.now());
    next();
});

router.use('/', express.static(path.join(__dirname, './404'))); // HALP!

module.exports = router;
```

I've played around with the directory (trying to use '404' vs './404'). I am testing this by entering "localhost:3000/error". So if my path is '/error', it should still use the parent path: '/'. The documentation states that as long as my route is placed last, it should still work. I tested it without express.static and used an anon function that prints error on console.

Is it impossible to use express.static() twice?

Comment: Yes, you can use more than one `express.static()`.  It's just middleware and you can have as many as you want. They will be searched in the order you register them.  It is not clear at all what you are trying to accomplish.  For static routing help, please show several examples of the exact URL that you want to load a particular file in your file system and show exactly where the file is in your file system.

Comment: Is it not possible to to use any path? I want to use the 'express.static()' on any path '/' besides the homepage. In other words, why is 'router.use('/', express.static(path.join(__dirname, './404');' not working? It works when I remove the static and just test console.log.

Comment: FYI, a custom 404 page does not require `express.static()` in any way.  Usually, you would just create the desired 404 middleware handler as the last middleware and then `res.sendFile()` whatever file you want to show.  A 404 handler example is shown here: https://expressjs.com/en/starter/faq.html.  If you just want to send a finished HTML file to the client (no server-side rendering), then use `res.sendFile(someLocalFilePath)` in the 404 middleware.

Comment: `express.static()` can be used several ways.  It can be configured to only come into play for certain paths of requests.  Or, it can be configured to check every single request to see if there's a static file that matches it's path.  You don't use `express.static()` for a 404 handler by definition.  If there's a file that matches the route request and `express.static()` finds it, then it's a 200 successful response, not a 404.  You use middleware to handler requests that found no other route and in that middleware, you set the response static to 404 and decide what to send the browser.

Comment: Another example of a 404 handler: https://www.hacksparrow.com/express-js-custom-error-pages-404-and-500.html

Comment: I swear I've read this paragraph at least a thousand times: " When a file is not found, instead of sending a 404 response, this module will instead call next() to move on to the next middleware, allowing for stacking and fall-backs." I'm going to go get my brain checked out. For the meantime, I'd like to thank you. I am deeply indebted to you. You are a gentlemen and a scholar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moving some of my comments into an answer since this led to your solution.

> For Express.js 4.x, is it possible to use express.static twice?

Yes, you can use `express.static()` as many times as you want.  It is middleware and, if it does not find a file matching the request, it just calls `next()` and allows the middleware chain to continue.  So, you can have as many of them as you want and they will each get to search for a matching file in the order you register them.

> I would like to show a custom 404 page (containing html, css, img, and ico). I know my 404 folder works when I replace the first public static homepage. However, I believe I am either not using routes the right way or it is not possible to set up two static folders.

You are mistakenly trying to use `express.static()` to implement a custom 404 page.  That is not what it does.  The usual way to implement a custom 404 page is with the last middleware handler in the chain.  When that gets hit, nothing else has found a match for the current request, therefore you send your custom 404 page.

That typically looks like this:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.status(404).sendFile(localPathToYour404Page);
});
```

See the "How do I handle 404 responses" section of this [Express starter FAQ](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/faq.html).

And, here's an [article on custom error pages](https://www.hacksparrow.com/express-js-custom-error-pages-404-and-500.html) that shows some other examples.

Comment: And a well deserved vote for best answer. But hopefully no one sees this shameful question. Haha!

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/jekku/users/blob/master/server.js#L41

Here's how I route my static files on an ExpressJS app. I usually don't do it in the routes, but I consider it as an 'initialization' process. It is possible to use ANY middleware twice or even more - as much as you want, keep that in mind.